# Need help on running PowerShell command related to Sharepoint Client ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, powershell-script

By referring i see that i need to run the command but when i try to run i am getting below error

[PowerShell Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/replace-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-add-in#prerequisites)

When i run i am getting below error  i am new to powershell and i dont know what is wrong i am doing i just installed Powershell and from windows i search powershell and i run the command

[image: po]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not import the module needed. First you will need to connect to O365. Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell). 
The article you referred has just listed the Prerequisites.

Ensure the following before you begin:
[Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39267) is installed on the development computer.

You can connect to Office 365 with PowerShell: Connect to Office 365 PowerShell

You are a tenant administrator for the Office 365 tenant (or a farm administrator on the farm) where the add-in was registered with the AppRegNew.aspx page.

Pay attention to the steps:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple !!

Just run the following 3 commands from a PowerShell which is opened as an administrator and your problem should get sorted.

1. install-module AzureAD
2. install-module AzureADPreview
3. install-module MSOnline